# Instantiating classes in the developer console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx, create-react-app

I've got a React/JSX app built with create-react-app. I have a state class `export class Foo { ... }` in `src/state/Foo.js`. I would like to instantiate some `Foo`s in the developer console for REPL debugging, but I can't figure out how to do that.

`let f = new Foo()` doesn't work, of course, because `Foo` is not in scope. `import Foo from './src/state/Foo.js'` produces a syntax error (which is not fixed by messing with the path to `Foo.js`). I suspect there would be problems anyway even if that did work, since the source is webpacked and the individual script files are gone.

This seems like it should be simple; what am I missing? How do I instantiate classes from my source in the developer console?

Comment: You can save it on the window object `window.Foo = Foo`

Comment: Which developer console exactly are you using? Does it support something like setting the environment to a specific file scope? Or maybe what you really want is a breakpoint in your file, while your application runs normally?

Comment: Try `const { Foo } = await import('./src/state/Foo.js');`